# how can I call a method stored in a parent uiviewcontroller from the uiviewcontroller embedded in a container in that controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController -let's call it parentViewController - and it contains a container. This container has embeddedViewController embedded in it.
Now, my parentViewController contains a method that prints something into the console:

```
func printSomeData(){
    print("some data")
}
```

embeddedViewController has a button with action asigned to it:

```
@IBAction func printSomething(sender: AnyObject) {
```

is there a way that I could call method `printSomeData` from `printSomething` in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways such as by implementing delegate or by posting NSNotification. Here I show the sample delegation pattern. This is exact scenario as your own controller but from this you can get some concept and if you implement this hope this will accomplished your goal.

```
    class ParentController:UIViewController,printing {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    //
  }

  func presentEmbadedController(){

    let embadedVC = EmbadedController()
    embadedVC.delegate = self

  }

  func printSomeData() {
    print("some date")
  }

}
```

Here is the protocol something like this

```
protocol printing{
 func printSomeData()
}
```

And then the EmbadedController like this

```
 class EmbadedController:UIViewController {

  var delegate: printing?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    //
  }

  @IBAction func printSomething(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let _ = delegate{
      delegate?.printSomeData()
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(...)